# Aguardando por um sinal dentro de um QQuickImageProvider

Tags: c++, qt, qml

Estou criando uma aplicação usando **QML** e o **Qt 5.2**. Nela uma `ListView` exibe vários itens, cada um com uma imagem e um texto associado. A imagem é construida com base em dados carregados de um servidor por **HTTP**. De forma simplificada, tenho o seguinde código:

```c++
MyProvider::MyProvider() :
    QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,
                        QQmlImageProviderBase::ForceAsynchronousImageLoading)
{ }

QImage MyProvider::requestImage(const QString& id, QSize* size, const QSize& requestedSize)
{
    // Obter dados JSON que me explicam como montar a imagem
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://myserver.com/api/imagedata/" + id));
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    QNetworkReply* reply = manager.get(request);

    // Aguardar pela resposta. Aqui está o problema
    QEventLoop loop;
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();

    // Ler a resposta e montar uma imagem com ela
    QImage img = produceImageFromJsonData(reply->readAll());
    delete reply;

    // Ajustar para o tamanho requisitado
    if (requestedSize.isValid())
        img = img.scaled(requestedSize, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    *size = img.size();
    return img;
}
```

O `MyProvider` é então registrado e usado no QML como `source` de cada `Image` da lista. O problema com esse código é que existe uma **race condition** nele. O `requestImage` é executado em uma **thread** diferente do resto aplicação. No momento que eu crio um **`QEventLoop`** e executo ele, eu estou permitindo que a minha thread receba e processe **qualquer evento** que ocorra. Como pode haver mais de uma thread executando esse loop, dois eventos podem ser enviados para o mesmo objeto ao mesmo tempo por threads diferentes. Eu obtenho um **crash** de difícil reprodução (aconteceu pela primeira vez hoje, depois de quase um mês de desenvolvimento).

O problema pode ser também reproduzido com esse código menor, mostrando que a simples existência de um `QEventLoop` desencadeia o crash:

```c++
MyProvider::MyProvider() :
    QQuickImageProvider(QQmlImageProviderBase::Image,
                        QQmlImageProviderBase::ForceAsynchronousImageLoading)
{ }

QImage MyProvider::requestImage(const QString& id, QSize* size, const QSize& requestedSize)
{
    QEventLoop loop;
    loop.exec();
    return QImage();
}
```

Encontrei um [**bugreport**](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-16249) que data do **Qt 4.7.1** onde o seguinte é dito:

> The problem is that the `QEventLoop` that is created in the imageprovider causes events to be delivered to the image reader which shares the thread. It receives these events while still processing a previous event. [...] It is not valid to run an event loop in the image provider.

Em resumo, não posso usar o `QEventLoop` na minha função. Então, como posso aguardar pelo `QNetworkReply` e apenas retornar da função quando a resposta chegar?

Comment: O QNetworkReply tem um sinal 'finished' (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkreply.html#finished) que é emitido quando a resposta terminou de ser processada. Você tentou utilizá-lo diretamente?

Comment: Foi justamente esse que usei `QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));`. O problema é que esperar por qualquer sinal implica em receber eventos.

Comment: Sim, mas o que eu quis dizer é: você tentou conectar o sinal em um método da sua própria classe e colocar lá a  chamada de 'produceImageFromJsonData' (algo como connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this /* slot no this, e não em loop */, SLOT(finished()));)? Em outras palavras, você realmente precisa do loop?

Comment: @LuizVieira, não resolve o problema, pois o QQuickImageProvider espera que eu retorne a QImage por aquela função. No momento que eu retornar a thread poderá ser destruída.

Comment: @Bacco, isso é exatamente o mesmo que o event loop. Mas note isso nao está na mesma thread que a UI,então eu não preciso me preocupar com congelamentos. O problema é que eu não posso processar eventos e o QNetworkReply precisa que eu os processe para funcionar (meramente usar um loop com um sleep dentro não funciona).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Você tem razão, desculpe. Bom, tenho outra sugestão de teste pra você: experimente utilizar Qt::QueuedConnection como o tipo da conexão. O default é 'auto', e como o QNetworkReply e o QEventLoop estão na mesma thread talvez o problema do bug report que vc citou (*It receives these events while still processing a previous event*) esteja ocorrendo por causa do envio direto. Quem sabe se ao forçar o enfileiramento do sinal de término o problema não mais ocorra (embora seja difícil de reproduzir, como você mencionou).

Comment: @LuizVieira Nada a se desculpar, está ajudando! Ao que entendi o meu `QEventLoop` está recebendo e processando sinais de outros objetos de outras threads (algum interno do QML que ta na thread da UI). Como tem mais de uma thread minha, esse objeto do QML recebe dois sinais ao mesmo tempo de threads separadas. Além disso o debugger mostrou que o crash acontecia com algum outro sinal, antes mesmo do sinal do `QNetworkReply` ser eviado. Consigo reproduzir o problema pondo apenas `QEventLoop().exec();` dentro daquela função, deletando todo o resto.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Que probleminha cabeludo, heim? hehe O erro ainda ocorre (ou se altera) se você usar QEventLoop().exec(QEventLoop::ExcludeUserInputEvents); ?

Comment: @LuizVieira Sim, tentei isso também. Infelizmente tenho o mesmo crash.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Imaginei que você já tivesse testado, mas não custava perguntar. :) Bom, vou pesquisar mais assim que tiver mais tempo. Se tiver mais alguma sugestão eu volto a postar. Boa sorte ai.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desconheço uma forma de aguardar pelo sinal ali. Também não é possível fazer a thread dormir em um loop checando se os dados chegaram manualmente pois o `QNetworkReply` depende do *event loop* para ser notificado do recebimento da resposta.

---

Sendo assim, parti para uma implementação diferente da mesma ideia. Em vez de criar um provedor de imagens e deixar que a engine se encarregue por tudo no lugar, escolhi fazer de forma mais manual.

Interface anterior:

```qml
Image {
  id: avatar
  source: "image://myimageprovider/" + avatarImageId
}
```

Nova interface:

```qml
Image {
  id: avatar
}

MyImageLoader {
  sourceId: avatarImageId
  target: avatar
}
```

Meu objetivo se tornou implementar o componente `MyImageLoader` de forma que fizesse a operação desejada. Segue a minha implementação:

`myimageloader.hpp`:

```c++
class MyImageLoader : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString sourceId READ sourceId WRITE setSourceId)
    Q_PROPERTY(QObject* target READ target WRITE setTarget)

public:
    MyImageLoader(QObject* parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}

    QString sourceId() const { return _sourceId; }
    void setSourceId(const QString& sourceId) { _sourceId = sourceId; beginDownload(); }

    QObject* target() const { return _target; }
    void setTarget(QObject* target) {_target = target; setTargetSource(); }

private:
    void beginDownload();
    void endDownload();
    void setTargetSource();
    QString cacheFile();

    QNetworkAccessManager _manager;
    QNetworkReply* _reply = nullptr;
    QString _sourceId;
    QObject* _target = nullptr;
};
```

`myimageloader.cpp`:

```c++
void MyImageLoader::beginDownload() {
    if (QFile::exists(cacheFile()))
        return setTargetSource();

    delete _reply;
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://myserver.com/api/imagedata/" + _sourceId));
    request.setRawHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    _reply = _manager.get(request);
    connect(_reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, this, &MyImageLoader::endDownload);
}

void MyImageLoader::endDownload() {
    QImage img = produceImageFromJsonData(_reply->readAll());
    delete _reply;
    img.save(cacheFile());
    setTargetSource();
}

void MyImageLoader::setTargetSource() {
    if (!_target) return;

    QString file = cacheFile();
    _target->setProperty("source", QFile::exists(file) ? "file:///" + file : "");
}

QString MyImageLoader::cacheFile() {
    return QDir::temp().filePath(_sourceId + ".png");
}
```

A grande diferença é que não estou a usar threads. Tudo ocorre em uma única thread (a mesma que renderiza a cena). Não há travamento da interface durante o carregamento por conta dos sinais. Todas essas funções retornam imediatamente e não bloqueiam.

A desvantagem é que sou obrigado a salvar a imagem em um arquivo. Não é um problema para mim, já que planejava fazer cache dos dados de qualquer maneira.

Isso não responde a pergunta em si, mas resolve meu problema.